# How to set environment variables for tex packages path in R?

Tags: latex, r, texlive, rstudio

When trying to build a book from a Rstudio project I get the following error:

```
output file: thesis.knit.md

sh: 1: pdflatex: not found
Error: Failed to compile thesis.tex.
Execution halted
```

That goes the same using `rmarkdown::render()`.

As suggested [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207813468-pdflatex-not-found-only-for-button) in Rstudio community support thread, I tried modifying the environment variable `PATH` by including the  `pathval <- "...:/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/"`, which is the local installation path for all binaries of texlive packages including the `pdflatex` package

```
pathname <- "PATH"
pathval <- "/home/deependra/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/"
args <- list(pathval)
names(args) <- pathname
do.call(Sys.setenv, args)
```

Now the that the `Sys.getenv("PATH")` shows:

```
[1] "/home/deependra/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin /sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/"
```

I can't help but wonder, why the error remains unresolved.

**Side-query**

Although, strictly speaking yet another directory called "x86_64-linux" exists between .../bin and the actual program link files to the binaries, I don't think that should be the problem, not when setting .bashrc variable at least. Or, is it somehow problematic in `R`?

Anybody suggesting something here would be much thanked for.

Comment: Did you restart the application or made anything else that your application would be aware of PATH change? Is it possible that you changed the PATH and the application did not know about that? If you set PATH in .bashrc, you need to make sure .bashrc is executed. The easiest way is to logout and login again.

Comment: @nobody Thanks for the motivation. My fault with the approach was that I should have included the full path (with the intermediate directory, "x86_64-linux") in the "PATH" environment variable. Now It's corrected with just the tweak.